# Why do a SSL certificate thumbprint would change ?

Tags: ssl, adfs

For a reason i'd like to know, the thumbprint of the ssl certificate i use on ADFS changed this morning and i can't figure out why. It does not look like anybody reinstalled the certificate, it is the same certificate as before.

Web.config, ensuring the the security token was encrypted with this certificate, verified by the thumbprint.

```
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <audienceUris>
      <add value="https://localhost:44302/" />
    </audienceUris>
    <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
      <authority name="http://host.domain.com/adfs/services/trust">
        <keys>
          <add thumbprint="here_is_a_thumbprint" />
        </keys>
        <validIssuers>
          <add name="http://host.domain.com/adfs/services/trust" />
        </validIssuers>
      </authority>
    </issuerNameRegistry>
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

It is my understanding that the Thumbprint is unique worlwide for each of its installation ( am i right? ) and the only time it changes is when it is reinstalled ( am i also right ? )

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the thumbprint of the SSL certificate - it's the thumbprint of the signing certificate. Your signing certificate has rolled over.